# Spring Boot: Is there a best practice for deciding which static values to store in a application.properties file and which values to store in java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file, application.properties

I hava a spring boot web application with multiple GUI views. I'm having trouble to decide which values to store directly as an instance in a Java Class and which values i should store in the application.properties file. For Example:

- I'm defining an interval of how often a validity of a business object is checked.
- I'm defining ui error messages for handeled errors.

Are there any defined best practices for those kind of questions, and if there aren't: how do you guys handle it?

Answer (score 4):

There are usually three reasons for putting properties into config file:

- properties that you may want to have different values of depending on the environment (local vs dev vs production) - in this case build pipeline will inject config for given environment
- properties that you think you may want to change at runtime. If you have it in the config file you won't have to recompile your application. However, this reason now is rarely valid since applications usually run in multiple instances and you definitely don't want to manually change it in all of them - for this reason you'd need to use some kid of configuration server, that can deliver new configs to services in the runtime
- properties that you suspect you may change in future - if you have them in config file, it's easy to find them (instead of searching through source code)